# Cannot register pig UDF jar

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having problems with a particular UDF jar and have so far been unable to figure out where to begin. I have a way of testing the jar from the command line and it works. If I REGISTER the jar in a pig script, pig fails to create a jar for the job. I can register other jars without trouble and this jar was working until a few days ago. Here is the output when running the pig script:

```
[michael@hadoop01 logitech-correlation]$ pig -f MatchWithClassifier.pig -param date=20130301 -param siteId=0
2013-05-10 11:20:30,523 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.10.0-cdh4.1.2 (rexported) compiled Nov 01 2012, 18:38:58
2013-05-10 11:20:30,524 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/michael/correlation/pig_1368210030521.log
2013-05-10 11:20:30,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://hadoop01/
2013-05-10 11:20:31,346 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: hadoop01.dev.terapeak.com:8021
2013-05-10 11:20:32,143 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: FILTER
2013-05-10 11:20:32,390 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2013-05-10 11:20:32,422 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2013-05-10 11:20:32,422 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2013-05-10 11:20:32,508 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2013-05-10 11:20:32,518 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2013-05-10 11:20:32,522 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job5623238576559565298.jar
2013-05-10 11:20:36,398 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
Details at logfile: /home/michael/correlation/pig_1368210030521.log
```

The stack trace is below:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:727)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:259)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:180)
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1275)
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1260)
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1250)
  at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:362)
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:132)
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:193)
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
  at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
  at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:430)
  at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:163)
  at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:194)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.JarManager.addStream(JarManager.java:242)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.JarManager.mergeJar(JarManager.java:216)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.JarManager.mergeJar(JarManager.java:206)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.util.JarManager.createJar(JarManager.java:126)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:411)
  ... 17 more
================================================================================
```

Based on this I would think the problem is from the "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back" exception. Is pig having some issue reading the jar?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the jar? Have you tried registering it in Grunt shell? Does the error happen when you register the jar, or when you try to run a function from it? Can you paste the error you get in Grunt, when you get it, and a full pig script that results in this error?

Comment: To register it through the grunt shell do I simply enter a REGISTER command? Currently I have the script set to register the jar and simply print out a couple columns of data without invoking any functions in the jar. Like that it fails while building the jar for hadoop. If I comment out the register command from my pig script it works.

Comment: Yes. You'll just do something like:

REGISTER '/path/to/some.jar';

I want to see if just putting that by itself into grunt shell forces the same error. If it does, try the same with some other jar that you know works with the same path.

Comment: That does not result in an error. Playing around with the pig scripts I also found the error only occurs once pig tries to create a jar to send to hadoop. It doesn't happen with other jars. I've added the output from running the job above.

Comment: What happens when you register the jar in grunt and then dump/store some data (without using any functions from the jar vs with using functions from the jar)? What happens when you run the whole script locally (pig -x local ...)?